# Set cursor from EditText1 to EditText2

Tags: android, button, cursor

I want to move the cursor from an EditText1 to an EditText2 when on button action that will reset all EditTexts, I tried this but it didn't work:

```
final Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

 button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {

         vol.setText("");
         kil.setText("");
         cons.setText("");

         Editable e = vol.getText();
         int position = vol.length();
         Selection.setSelection(e,position);
     }
     });
```

Any idea how to resolve this problem?

Comment: You might want to post an own answer and accept it. Your edit is easy to overlook and the answer below is unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`requestFocus()` can solve the problem, I add this function in my .java file and it works :).
Example:

```
vol = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.volume2);
vol.requestFocus();
```

If we want to set the cursor on the "volume2" EditText.

Answer (score 1):

Use the type ahead sense for your EditText.  Look for .focused or .setFocus, etc.  I have never done what you're trying to do but I'd start there.